How to create a custom locale for Luxon JS?
I'm migrating a large, date-focused application from Moment.js to Luxon. So far, Luxon has been great to work with, but I've hit a roadblock with a particular requirement:
I need to display dates using German formatting (e.g., 24-hour time, dd.MM.yyyy format) but with English names for days and months. With Moment.js, we achieved this by creating a custom locale (e.g., 'en-custom').
Is there a way to override or customize Luxon's locale data (which it gets from the Intl API as far as I can see) to achieve this mixed-language formatting? Specifically, I'm looking to mix formats from different locales (de for date formats and en for month/day names).
Any insights or examples on how to accomplish this with Luxon would be greatly appreciated.

DateTime.toFormat() isn't what you are looking for? Something like dt.setLocale("en").toFormat("cccc, dd LLLL yyyy")
